# can I get number of edges connected to a vertex

Tags: python, scripting, edges, select

I essentially want to put a fence up around the edge of my object, is there a way I can select all vertices with 3 edges connected to it?

[image]

```
for vertex in object:
    if vertex.connectededges == 3:
        select
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the 4 corners wouldn't get selected because they are connected to 2 edges.

However there is a handy operator with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> or Select>Select Similar then "Amount of connecting edges"

[image]

**Alternatively**, if used in a script, you can use the operator :

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='EDGE', threshold=0.01)
```

But you need to first select some vertices.

[image]

**If you can't select the vertices** before running your script, use this :

```
import bpy
import bmesh

mesh = bpy.context.object.data  # Get selected object's mesh

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh) 
# Create new edit mode bmesh to easily acces mesh data


for v in bm.verts:
    v.select_set(len(v.link_edges) in (2,3))
# Select all vertices that have 2 or 3 links and deselect the others

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)  # Transfer the data back to the object's mesh
```

[Source](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/select-all-verts-that-has-4-edges-connected/5328) and [Source 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173773/86891)

Comment: Would be wary of the method used in copied bmesh script.  If there are changes to mesh in edit mode could be trashed, since it is loading the bmesh then toggling out of edit mode, writing to mesh with selection, then toggling into edit mode.  Would either use an edit mode bmesh, or load the mesh **after** toggling into object object.  _Confirmed..Simple test:  Default cube > edit mode > move some verts, > run script > back to default cube._

Comment: @batFINGER I understand, honest mistake due to my inexperience ! Would you be willing to edit the answer to provide a more suitable method since I don't (yet) know the difference between edit mode bmesh and object mode bmesh ? (even if your answer is obviously the simplest one)

Comment: Not sure re simplest, one that selects boundaries. If the grid was poked for example, still selects boundaries.  Would simply use an edit mode bmesh.  Wonder about the `ob.select_set` if it is to become default and setting via `v.select = True` is going to be phased out.  Accidentally reverted to old ways in my answer lol.

Comment: Okay I got it from your answer, it's shorter and less error-prone as you said. In other languages direct attribute access is a bit frowned upon so I guess the setter usage is more encouraged ?

Answer (score 6):

**Boundary edges**

> I essentially want to put a fence up around the edge of my object

IMO Simplest here to select edges that are boundaries, ie are connected to only one face.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.edit_object

me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for e in bm.edges:
    e.select = e.is_boundary

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

The vertex selection is implied by the edges.  .. which is why I could have used

```
e.select_set(e.is_boundary)
```

> **`BMEdge.select_set(select):`**
>
> Set the selection. This is different from the *select* attribute
>   because it updates the selection state of associated geometry.

Although in this case I'm of the belief that the verts of an edge are selected with the edge. So

```
verts = set(v for e in boundary_edges for v in e.verts)
```

will be same as selected verts.

```
v for v in bm.verts if v.select
```

**Using the bmesh to extrude those edges.**

Rather than selecting the edges, can instead feed them directly into bmesh operators. For the example below the vertices created as a result of extruding boundary edges are fed into transform operator, and moved up one in Z.

[image]
*Result on 10 x 10 default grid*

Notice newly created geometry added with bmesh is unselected by default.  Run both these scripts below in edit mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bmesh.types import BMVert
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = bpy.context.edit_object

me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.transform(
    bm,
    verts = [
            e for e in 
                bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(
                    bm,
                    edges=[e for e in bm.edges if e.is_boundary],
            )["geom"] 
            if isinstance(e, BMVert)
            ],
    matrix=Matrix.Translation((0, 0, 1)),
    )

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.

1. Select one vertex with 3 connected edges
2. Go to *Select > Similar > Amount of connecting edges*
3. Done.

[image]